# Extracting data from FileMaker Pro 5.5 via a SQL client

Tags: filemaker

I need to extract and see the data in FileMaker Pro 5.5.
Is there an easy method to hooking up a SQL client?
At a minimum, if I cannot easily extract the data, I'd like to see the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Filemaker 5.5 you can create a view and simply drag all the field in it. You can also use the [Filemaker ODBC driver](http://www.filemaker.com/downloads/pdf/FMP_ODBC_gettingstarted.pdf) to connect. You'll need to have your filemaker client open for this to work if I remember correctly (It's been a while since I've used filemaker).